# Is there a Julia function to do appropriate hostname resolution?

Tags: julia

I'm from the Java background and began to have an interest in Julia some months back. In Java, I will just import the java.net package and use the InetAddress method as follows;

```
InetAddress address=InetAddress.getByName("www.stackoverflow.com");
System.out.prinln(address.getHostAddress());
```

I am really curious to know how it's been done in Julia. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yes! indeed can be done in just one line of code.

[From Julia Docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.3/manual/networking-and-streams/#Resolving-IP-Addresses-1)

In Julia, We will use sockets. This functionality is in the standard library called Sockets. And at the base of this functionality is `getaddrinfo` which will do the appropriate address resolution. In your Julia REPL, do the following:

```
using Sockets
getaddrinfo("www.stackoverflow.com")
"216.58.204.228"
```

Hope this helps.